# How to run two functions of the same class in different threads

Tags: qt, class, qthread

Hi I have a class named search and this class has two member functions. The consumer and the producer. This is the way I have activated these functions as two threads in qt.

```
thread1 = new QThread();
thread2 = new QThread();
mySearch = new Search() ;

mySearch->moveToThread(thread1);

mySearch->moveToThread(thread2);


connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread1, SLOT(start()));
connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread2, SLOT(start()));

connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()),mySearch, SLOT(producer()));
connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()),mySearch, SLOT(consumer()));

connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(finishedscan()), thread1, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(finishedscan()), thread2, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

But, it seems that only one is activated. How should I activate both. Please let me know with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: A QObject can only "live" in a single thread. Thats by definition. You could create a wrapper around "Search" and let each wrapper live in a seperate thread

Comment: Thanks. I have a common circular buffer between these two threads. Will the consumer thread follow the changes of the buffer made by the producer if I define separate wrappers for each thread? If I write the two functions in two different classes then were should I define the common circular buffer? In the producer class or the consumer class? @Felix

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to run the two methods of the same object in two different threads. Assuming your `Search` class looks like this:

```
class Search : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void producer();
    void consumer();

signals:
    void workRequested();
    void finishedscan();
};
```

You would create a second class like this:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker(std::function<void()> task) :
        QObject{},
        _task{std::move(task)}
    {}

public slots:
    void work() {
        _task();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> _task;
};
```

And now you can implement the start:

```
thread1 = new QThread();
thread2 = new QThread();
mySearch = new Search();
auto worker1 = new Worker(std::bind(&Search::producer, mySearch));
auto worker2 = new Worker(std::bind(&Search::consumer, mySearch));

worker1->moveToThread(thread1);
worker2->moveToThread(thread2);

connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread1, SLOT(start()));
connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(workRequested()), thread2, SLOT(start()));

connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()),worker1, SLOT(work()));
connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()),worker2, SLOT(work()));

connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(finishedscan()), thread1, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(mySearch, SIGNAL(finishedscan()), thread2, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

**Important:** While this solution solves how to *start* the two tasks on different threads, stopping won't work yet as `QThread::quit` only works if the thread returns to the eventloop! If your producer/consumer methods do **not** return to the eventloop and use it to perform tasks, write so in the comments and I will update the answer to handle that case as well.

---

**EDIT:** Since stopping i the above solution only works, if producer/consumer return to the eventloop - which is not the case according to OP, you have to manually notify the worker that it should stop working to gracefully quit the thread.

For the first solution, your worker has to periodically check, if it should stop working. For example:

```
MySearch::producer() {
    while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested() {
        //do some work 
    }
}
```

And secondly, you have to adjust how you quit the thread:

```
connect(mySearch, &MySearch::finishedscan, thread1, [thread1](){
    thread1->requestInterruption();
    thread1->quit();
}, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

**Note:** Regardless of how you quit your threads, you should always wait for them in the main thread to finish their work before exiting:

```
thread1->wait();
```

Finally, you mentioned in the comments that you use `CTRL+C` to quit the application - make shure to register a signal handler to catch `SIGINT` and stop you application gracefully, as the default `SIGINT` will just terminate it, without proper cleanup

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't exactly understand what you mean by event loop. Both the producer and consumer thread keep on working until I use ctrl+c. The producer fills the buffer and the consumer reads the buffer and shows the values in a Qtable @Felix

Comment: In that case, using quit will not work (you should really read on QThread to understand how it works). You can either use `terminate` or use logic inside the worker to handle the quit. I will update the answer